# How to add GIF in beamer and view in Pympress

Tags: beamer, pdf, presentations, animations, gif

I'm using Pympress 1.5.1, I tried to add a gif file in beamer with two methods

1- Using \movie command

```
\documentclass[serif,12pt,aspectratio=169,compress,xcolor={dvipsnames}]{beamer}
\mode<presentation>
\usetheme{Warsaw}
\setbeamertemplate{navigation symbols}{}
\definecolor{colorA}{RGB}{96, 34, 59}
\definecolor{colorB}{RGB}{140, 151, 154}

\setbeamercolor{structure}{fg=colorA,bg=colorB}


%=================================================
% packages and new commands
%=================================================
\usepackage[ruled, linesnumbered, vlined]{algorithm2e}
\usepackage{epsfig, subfigure, amssymb, multirow, algorithmic, amsmath}
\newcommand*{\superscript}[1]{\ensuremath{^{\rm #1}}}
\newcommand*{\subscript}[1]{\ensuremath{_{\rm #1}}}

\usepackage{relsize}
\usepackage{multimedia}  %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage[all]{xy}
\usepackage{times}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{animate}
\usepackage{ragged2e}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage[edges]{forest}
\usetikzlibrary{shadows,arrows.meta}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{indentfirst}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[timeinterval=1]{tdclock}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{mwe}
\usepackage{collectbox}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}    
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\movie[width=5cm,height=5cm]{}{gif/direction4motor.gif}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

2- Convert gif file to png images and then use \animategraphics

```
\animategraphics[autoplay, width=0.4\linewidth]{10}{gif/Direction4motor-}{0}{48}
```

The first method didn't show anything in Pympress

The second method wasn't animated as a frozen image, Adobe Reader worked like a charm, but Pympress wasn't.

Any help, please

Comment: Maybe an alternative is to convert the gif to avi or mp4 or some other 'real' movie format and then play it using the embedded VLC plugin in Pympress (using `\movie`). I have never tried that but according to the Github page it should be fairly easy (assuming Linux of course).

Comment: Unrelated to your problem, but you don't need amssymb, amsmath, hyperref and graphicx as beamer loads them for you. times is deprecated. float and indentfirst don't make a lot of sense with beamer and instead of multicol I's rather use beamer's own column mechanism

Comment: @Marijn I tried to use .avi format with \movie command but it didn't work, Pympress content is all black (not showing anything)!

Comment: @samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz Thanks, I'm definitely taking your advice

Comment: @DENA11 maybe the relevant VLC libraries for Python are not installed if the avi is not displayed? Or maybe the avi file itself is not ok, or your VLC does not have an avi codec installed, you could try playing it in VLC itself to see if it works at all.